# In MBA m1 activity monitor, processor name "java" is showing "kind" "intel"

Tags: java, macos, intel, apple-silicon, activity-monitor

In MBA m1 activity monitor, processor name "java" is showing "kind" "intel"., I just wanna know is there a java kind apple silicon or universal or is its just intel?
[image]

just asking for basic  information.

Answer (score 2):

## Intel versus Apple Silicon

You must have installed a [JDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) that is compiled for [Intel processors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) rather than Apple Silicon ([ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)-based) processors.

Mac computers with [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Silicon) are capable of running Intel-based apps via [Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)) [dynamic binary translation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation#Dynamic_binary_translation) technology provided by Apple.

For maximum performance and compatibility, I suggest you delete that installed JDK. Install a newly downloaded JDK built explicitly for Apple Silicon.

✅ Look for downloads marked as “Apple Silicon”, “ARM”, “AArch64”, or “M1”.

❌ Avoid those downloads marked as “Intel”, “x86”, “x86-64”, and “AMD64”.

You have a wide choice of vendors supplying JDKs for [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) on Apple Silicon. Off the top of my head, these vendors include [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/), [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/), SAP, Pivotal, Microsoft, [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc), Oracle, Red Hat/IBM, BellSoft. Some products are free-of-cost, some may require a fee, so read terms carefully.

---

If you are running an app that happens to be built on Java (rather than a JDK), contact the vendor of that app to see if they offer an edition compiled for Apple Silicon. If not, you may continue using the Intel-based edition — that is the purpose of *Rosetta 2*, to enable your new Mac to use older Intel-based apps not yet updated for Apple Silicon.